# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Reading from the stream has failed."

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ssh

I try to do a db connection with ssh.
The connection with ssh works.
But the method [MySqlDataAdapter].fill() throws the exception and i don't know why.
Sql Connection does work too, because if i change the password or something else, it throws different exception

```
    var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
    client.Connect();
    client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
    portForwarded.Start();
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection($"SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;UID={UID};PASSWORD={pwd};DATABASE={db}"))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {table}", con))
        {
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataRow drow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("From MySql: " + drow[1].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    client.Disconnect();
```

And the Exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Reading from the stream has failed."
EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream
```

Comment: What line of the code that you posted is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Kenster da.Fill(ds)